# Using RenderSections does not work in asp net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net. I have to use

```
 @section Scripts{}
```

but it does not work.
Keep in mind that I adjusted the below code in layout page:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

---

I read similar posts. But I still couldn't fix my problem.
Is there any other way I can use it?

Comment: What do you mean by `not work`? Do you get any error or exception? Share us the error message.

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors. It just not working. It seems that my razor page does not know this order

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What is your code? What is your expected result and current result? Maybe you could share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.

Comment: We need more information to help you. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It should be @section Scripts {} as opposed to @script Scripts{}

Comment: Excuse me, I was wrong in asking the question. Please read my question again. I am using @section in my project. Sorry again

Comment: Is there any other way I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

**section** allows you to add something in a view which will be added in the layout.

view

```
   @section scripts {

        <script>

          alert('hello world');

        </script>
}
```

layout

```
@RenderSection("scripts", false)
```

this named section scripts will be rendered wherever specified in layout.

@RenderSection also has 2 signatures:-

```
public HelperResult RenderSection(string name)
public HelperResult RenderSection(string name, bool required)
```

Comment: Excuse me, I was wrong in asking the question. Please read my question again. I am using @section in my project. Sorry again

Comment: Is there any other way I can use it?

Comment: why do you mean by ```not work```  ? what error or issue ..you are facing?

Comment: Can you post the code that you have in the {} in your scripts section?